# Как установить библиотеку GMP

Tags: c, windows

Что я должен сделать на Windows с компилятором gcc, чтобы мог просто писать `#include <gmp.h>`? Уж очень хочу попробовать на Си. Или есть альтернативы по длинной арифметике?

Comment: А у вас mingw точно без GMP версия GCC? Пробовали <GMP. h> вместо <gmp. h>?

Comment: @xmikex я сомневаюсь, что из того, что GCC сам зависит от GMP следует, что вместе с ним идет dev-пакет от нее.

Более того, я сомневаюсь, что *на венде* изменение регистра в имени файла может привести к каким-то позитивным изменениям

Comment: mingw-get install mingw32-gmp
mingw-get install mingw32-gmp-dev

Comment: Этот ответ мне помог. Огромнейшее Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если вы пользуетесь Visual Studio

1. Скачиваете и ставите [VCPKG](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)

   git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git
2. Устанавливаете

   cd vcpkg
   vcpkg-bootstrap.bat
3. Ставите GMP

   vcpkg install gmp:x64-windows

Comment: Занятно. Но не пользуюсь. Только sublime text)

Comment: А компилятор какой?

Comment: gcc (дополняем символы)

Answer (score 0):

Комментарий [@xmikex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1338859/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83-gmp/1338954#comment2370109_1338859) мне помог.

Решение:

```
mingw-get install mingw32-gmp.
```